# Check if all values are correct looping

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I would like to create a looping for check table.

If one of Col3 contains "**no**" variable **a** will be filled "**no**"

If all values of Col3 = yes, variable a will be return value **yes**

```
Col1  depend  isResolved
im1    SD10349    yes
im2    SD10349    no
im3    SD10349    yes
```

I have code as below

```
var frel = new SCFile("screlation");
var q = "depend=\"SD10349\"";
var rc = frel.doSelect(q);
var a="";
while(rc==RC_SUCCESS){
    switch(true){
        case frel.isResolved=="yes":
            a="yes";break;
        case frel.isResolved=="no":
            a="no";break;
    }
    rc=frel.getNext();
}
print(a);
```

but variable **a** always return **yes**. Appreciate for anything helps :)

Regards,
Okik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
  var frel = new SCFile("screlation");
    var q = "depend=\"SD10349\"";
    var rc = frel.doSelect(q);
    var a="";
    while(rc==RC_SUCCESS){
        a = (frel.isResolved=="yes")?"yes":"no"
        if(a=="no")break;
        rc=frel.getNext();
    }
    print(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In a `switch` statement, `switch` has the **expression parameter**, not the possible output of expression.

Try reversing the same

```
switch(frel.isResolved){ //expression as the parameter to switch
    case "yes": //check the 
        a="yes";break;
    case "no":
        a="no";break;
    default: 
      break;
 }
```

Or simply assign the value of `frel.isResolved` to `a`  (since that is what you are doing anyways)

```
a = frel.isResolved;
```

**Edit**

If you want to stop as soon as a no is encountered then

```
while( rc == RC_SUCCESS && a != "no" )
{
    a = frel.isResolved;
    rc = frel.getNext();
}
```

Comment: this will still return yes if there is a "yes" after a "no" as the once the "no" is set still in the next loop a is reset to yes

Comment: @js_noob Maybe I missed out on it - Is there a requirement that loop should end once a `no` is encountered?

Comment: @ gurvinder372 not required, hence break if no encountered :)

Comment: @js_noob that `break` (in OP's code) is breaking out of `switch`, not `while`.

Comment: I got it, i had put up a solution, i was refering it there@ gurvinder372

Comment: @js_noob oh, ok

Answer (score 0):

here problem is your not clearing the previous value. clear the previous value. after first case make the a value as null or empty.

after rc=frel.getNext(); statement clear the a variable value before going to the next loop.

a.val('');